# find 3 number from top with consider than same value

Tags: java, android

in this array as :

```
int[] value = {15, 15, 9, 9, 9, 12, 8, 8, 4};
```

i'm trying to get 3 number from top expected with same value for example:

```
value:15 - index: 1
value:15 - index: 1
value:9  - index: 2
value:9  - index: 2
value:9  - index: 2
value:12 - index: 3
```

i wrote this below code and that can sort them with largest values in array, but i can't add index as know for three level. for example:

```
int[]                 value = {15, 15, 9, 9, 9, 12, 8, 8, 4};
Map<Integer, Integer> map   = new HashMap<>();
for (int k = 0; k < value.length; k++)
    map.put(k, value[k]);
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list =
        new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()));
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> large : list)
    Log.e("value = ", large.getValue() + " , Index = " + large.getKey());
```

output is:

```
value =: 15 , Index = 0
value =: 15 , Index = 1
value =: 12 , Index = 5
value =: 9 , Index = 3
value =: 9 , Index = 4
value =: 9 , Index = 2
value =: 8 , Index = 7
value =: 8 , Index = 6
value =: 4 , Index = 8
```

how can i resolve this problem and correct index? Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear - do you want the first three unique numbers in the array, or do you want to sort them and find the three smallest unique values?

Comment: not unique, because maybe in this array we have same value such as `9` i'm trying to sort them from largest number to smallest with consider than same value , for example: `value:15 - index: 1
value:15 - index: 1
value:9  - index: 2
value:9  - index: 2
value:9  - index: 2
value:12 - index: 3`, in that i have one number in `index1`, three number as 9 in `index2` and `12` in `index3`, @Prisoner

Comment: Your example does NOT show them ordered from largest to smallest tho. It just shows them in the order they are in the input array.

Comment: @Prisoner yes i can't implementing that, my problem is on `index`

Comment: So are you trying to sort giving weight first to the number of times something appears in the array? Please give us more examples or be a little more clear about what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, you're not trying to do any sorting - just determining positioning.

```
int[] value = {15, 15, 9, 9, 9, 12, 8, 8, 4};

int index = 1;
int lastValue = value[0];
for( int co=0; co<value.length; co++ ){
    int thisValue = value[co];
    if( thisValue != lastValue ){
        index++;
        lastValue = thisValue;
    }
    System.out.println( "Value =: "+thisValue+" , Index = "+index );
}
```

Gives the desired output

```
Value =: 15 , Index = 1
Value =: 15 , Index = 1
Value =: 9 , Index = 2
Value =: 9 , Index = 2
Value =: 9 , Index = 2
Value =: 12 , Index = 3
Value =: 8 , Index = 4
Value =: 8 , Index = 4
Value =: 4 , Index = 5
```